# Ember.js - How to bind a view to a controller instance created by the router

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm using the latest build of Ember.js. I have an Ember app that displays a bar chart using flot.js. A view is bound to a singleton Object Controller to dynamically update the chart. I have a simple jsbin demo of this working here: http://jsbin.com/edosaf/2/edit. Note that this demo creates the cardController Object instead of extending it. Here is the relevant code:

```
App.cardController = Ember.ObjectController.create({
  id: 1,
  name: 'Visa',
  chartData: [ [2011, 450], [2012, 550], [2013, 320] ]
});

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application',
    chartValuesBinding: 'App.cardController.chartData'
});
```

I need to change the above code to extend the cardController instead of creating it while still binding it to the view.

I want to expand on this demo using different bar chart data based on the card_id passed into the url. The routing will look like #/card/:card_id. I am confused with how to bind my ChartView to different instances of my Card ObjectController. My thought is to have a Cards ArrayController to manage all of the credit card objects. Then have a Card ObjectController for managing the active card which will be bound to the ArrayController and also the ChartView.

Binding:
Cards ArrayController => Card ObjectController => Chart View

I created another jsbin that attempts to implement the desired routing and a Cards ArrayController (app does not work): http://jsbin.com/edosaf/4/edit

How can I bind a view to a controller instance created by the ember router? With this example, how would you recommended architecting the ember app to bind the CardController Object to the ChartView using the routing #/card/:card_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I bind a view to a controller instance created by the ember router?

Typically each of your views has a matching controller singleton. For example, within `ApplicationView` you can access the singleton `ApplicationController` via the `controller` property.

Whenever you need to access something else from the view, it should be done via it's controller. Then use `needs` array to connect controllers.

```
ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['card']
});

ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  chartValuesBinding: 'controllers.card.chartData'      
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! I was didn't know that controllers can be referenced like this in views.